# What Spring Cloud Services should be grouped together

Tags: spring-cloud

So far I have the following:

- Cloud Config Server
- Eureka Server
- Zuul Server

Is it recommended to group any of these together? It's a bit of a pain doing development with so many different servers. I am thinking of structuring my code modules in a way which would allow for me to change how I deploy the different services either stand-alone or combined to minimise the configuration overhead, but I don't want to do this if their are negative effects I am not aware of.

Comment: In Intellij https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248-multirun can ease the pain.

Comment: zuul is an edge service, so I would definitely not combine it. The others can be combined for development.